# The EditButton for NavigationView is not working properly for iPad ( But correct for iPhone)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I am new in SwiftUI developing, In a SwiftUI project, I created a list of items then I followed the tips in this link to  enabled edit button for this,

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editbutton

It works properly for iPhone interface, But in iPad, It has a very strange behaviour. Look at this video below to see how it works in iPad.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U63V.jpg

If you check this, the way it shows in iPad, when the Edit button text wants to turn to Done, the text steps forward and also creates a transparency with done and edit while it works properly and smooth and fixed in iPhone. I wonder if there might be any special settings for iPad interface in SwiftUI that would fix this problem.

This is my code for this:

```
struct QRCreator: View {

@State var showingCreateView = false

@State public var fruits = [
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Papaya",
    "Mango"
]

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        
            List {
                ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit)
                }
                .onDelete { fruits.remove(atOffsets: $0) }
                .onMove { fruits.move(fromOffsets: $0, toOffset: $1) }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Fruits2")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                    
                                    Button(action: {
                
                showingCreateView = true
            }){
                Image(systemName: "plus.viewfinder")
                    .font(.largeTitle)   
            }
            )
        
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
              
            }
        }
}
```

and here is ContentView which I define three tabs in it like this

```
TabView
    {
        NavigationView{
            
            QRScanner()
        }
            .tabItem
        {
            Image(systemName: "qrcode.viewfinder")
            Text("Scanner")
        }
        
        NavigationView {
            QRCreator()
        }
            .tabItem
        {
            Image(systemName: "doc.fill.badge.plus")
            Text("Creator")
        }
        NavigationView
        {
            QRSetting()
        }
            .tabItem
        {
            Image(systemName: "gear")
            Text("Setting")
        }
                 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two layers at play:

1. From the screen recording, it would appear that your NavigationView is actually wrapped by another NavigationView (or NavigationStack/SplitView) somewhere further up the view hierarchy in your implementation. Besides the odd layout, this also creates a tricky situation in regards to toolbar items like your buttons, and the [EditMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editmode) [environment value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues) that EditButton manipulates.
2. There is an iPad-specific animation bug in SwiftUI's implementation of EditButton. When clicked with a mouse/trackpad as in your screen recording, the button briefly shows both labels ("Edit" & "Done") at the same time. This doesn't happen when you tap the button directly.

It is only when issues 1 & 2 collide, that I actually run into the more problematic behavior that you've captured: the button jumps and the list also jumps.

If I keep everything as you have shown it (including the doubled-up NavigationViews), but *tap* the button instead of clicking it with a cursor, things seem fine (although I would expect other possible issues down the road).

If I get rid of the outer NavigationView, but *click* the button, the button itself still exhibits a slightly odd animation, but it is nowhere near as bad as before. And most importantly, the list animates and behaves correctly.

I tried a couple of approaches to work around the button's remaining animation bug, but nothing short of re-implementing a custom edit button worked.

PS: I know you might've already come across this, but since you said that you're just starting out with iOS 16 introduced new views and APIs for navigation (and in typical fashion for SwiftUI's documentation, older pages like the one for EditButton have not been updated). Depending on how complex your app is, switching later on can be a bit of a pain, so here's a good WWDC video introducing the new API: [The SwiftUI cookbook for navigation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10054/) as well as [some](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/06/15/mastering-navigationstack-in-swiftui-navigator-pattern/) [blog](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/10/05/mastering-navigationstack-in-swiftui-navigationpath/) [posts](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2022/06/21/mastering-navigationstack-in-swiftui-deep-linking/).

Comment: Thank you so so much. I really appreciate for the time you put on this issue and help me this long with worthy information. For the tip number one,  I have a question, If you take a look at my codes, you will see the structure, It has another issue, The list title ( Here is Fruits ) repeats two times, Can you help me just to make it as standard as possible?

Comment: Of course! Happy that you found it helpful. About the navigation title repeating … I really feel you must have another NavigationView somewhere else in the project (e.g. wherever you use instances of the QRCreator view you posted, or even all the way up at the App struct level?). If you search the project (Command+Shift+F to search all files) for ‘NavigationView’, ‘NavigationStack’, or ‘NavigationSplitView’, does something else show up besides the use of NavigationView in QRCreator?

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me work on it , I feel that I can count on your help for my project. Anyway Thank you so much

Comment: According to your previous advice, I put lots of efforts on it and yea I did it. Now I get rid of nested NavigationView and also Right now , The animated Edit Done button for the list looks much better. Thank you so many times

Comment: So happy to hear that, @nedaDerakhshesh. Good luck with the app.